# Div. Занять оставшееся место

Tags: html, css

Возникла проблема с блочной вёрсткой. Допустим, у нас есть 3 блока:

```
<div class="sidebar-left">
</div>
<div class="content">
</div>
<div class="sidebar-right">
</div>
```

Ширина `sidebar-left` и `sidebar-right` равна `300px` и `250px` соответственно. `sidebar-left` находится слева, `sidebar-right` – справа, `content` – между ними.

Как сделать так, чтобы ширина `content` занимала всё оставшееся место?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032914/how-to-make-a-div-to-fill-a-remaining-horizontal-space

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873832/make-a-div-fill-up-the-remaining-width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вводим дополнительный блок wrapper и работаем с дивами как с таблицей. И резиновое и вашим требованиям соответствует.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar-left {
  width: 300px;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}

.sidebar-right {
  width: 250px;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar-left">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-right">
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/en7dv0jw/

Извиняюсь за дублирование css свойств.

Answer (score 11):

#### Современный способ. Flexbox

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar-left {
  flex: 0 0 300px;
}

.sidebar-right {
  flex: 0 0 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar-left">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
    <div class="content">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-right">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Современный способ. Grid

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar-left">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
    <div class="content">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-right">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Для того, чтобы это работало также в IE применяем старый синтаксис и явно задаём положение каждого элемента:

```css
.container {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 300px 1fr 250px;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr 250px;
}

.content {
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
}

.sidebar-left {
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar-left">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
    <div class="content">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-right">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Классика. `float` и `overflow: hidden`.

```css
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.content {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar-left {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}

.sidebar-right {
  float: right;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container clearfix">
  <div class="sidebar-left">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-right">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Почему `overflow: hidden` работает можно почитать в [статье на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/48383/).